# Есть ли альтернатива OllyDbg под Mac OS X?

Tags: отладка, ассемблер, macos

С OC Windows все понятно: для нее OllyDbg есть, а есть где-нибудь в природе достойная замена OllyDbg, но строго под Mac OS X?

Comment: gdb+otx да IDA, что тут ещё подсказать. Хотя нет, есть ещё один мощный отладчик — [radare](http://radare.org/y/?p=examples&f=adv).

Comment: Про IDA на буржуйских форумах говорят что он не блещит, не хватает некоторых функций пока смотрю в сторону  Нex fiend ну конечно GDB

Comment: @x86-64

- Очень интересно, что тогда блещет, если не `IDA.` Или, может быть, все эти люди знают 10000 аналогов `HexRays`?

- Как вы можете смотреть в сторону `Hex-`редактора в контексте разговора про дебаггеры / дизассемблеры?

Comment: Ну и что посмотрел в сторону Нex fiend, посмотрел и оставил до лучших времен попробую заюзать IDA, а чего такого суперского в HexRays?

Comment: @x86-64 просто `debugger` и `hex-viewer/disassembler` — это совершенно разные вещи, которые лишь дополняют (но никак не заменяют) друг друга.  
В качестве дополнения к GDB рекомендую [.gdbinit](http://reverse.put.as/gdbinit/) от fG!, если не используете какой-либо свой.

Comment: @VioLet большое спасибо за дополнение, попробую заюзать!